# Google maps V2 changing Fragments

Tags: java, android, maps

I've got this app which uses fragment transactions and I'm getting difficulties destroying the maps between fragments. This makes it difficult to use google maps for different "actions", like: adding markers to the map on a fragment and adding a polyline on the other in the same application. Can someone help me understand how it is possible to implement a worthy solucion for that?

Comment: what do you mean by "difficulties destroying the maps between fragments"?

Comment: I mean, when I change from a fragment to another, the map "freezes" and doesn't make the changes I want it to make on the new fragment.

Comment: code or didn't happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of an easy one this one. Solved it out just by creating a new instance of the map each time the fragment is loaded (calling it on the OnCreateView method).

Thanks for the help.